# How do I set the keras backend in python dynamically when loaded using supervisor

Tags: keras, backend, theano, supervisord

How do I set the keras backend in python dynamically when loaded using supervisor?. When I load the python file using supervisor, the environmental variables seem to override the backend setup in the below code.

```
from keras import backend as K
import os
os.environ['KERAS_BACKEND'] = 'theano'
reload(K)
```

In the environmental variables, Keras backend is defined as 'tensorflow' and so the scripts starts with 'tensorflow' backend. The above set of lines doesn't work.